# Why the selected value in the ModalPopUp is not reflected and shown in the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a web-based suggestions box program for my company where the employees can submit any safety suggestions they have. Now, I am working on the Administration part of this system.

The Admin will be able to see all suggestions listed in a GridView control. In the last column of the GridView, the status will be listed there. When the Admin clicks on the status of one of these suggestion, a new pop-up window (asp.net ajax ModalPopUpExtender) will be appeared with listing all the possible status such as: actioned, approved... etc. And when the Admin selects one of these status, the status of the suggestion will be updated in the database. ***I wrote the code but still it doesn't update the status of the suggestion,***

**so could you please help me in modifying it?**

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name...
SafetySuggestionsLog: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
SafetySuggestionsStatus: ID, Status
```

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="900px" CssClass="mGrid" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="alt" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "True" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="DivisionShortcut" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

                <%-- This to make status be opened and edited through the Ajax ModalPopUp Window --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSuggestionStatus" Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'
                                        OnClick="lnkSuggestionStatus_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />--%>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp" style="display:none" />

        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender1"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp" 
                                        PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" 
                                        BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                                        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle" 
                                        OkControlID="OKButton">
        </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopUp">

                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StatusList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                            RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left" DataSourceID="SuggestionStatusDataSource"
                                            DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID">
                        <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="ACTIONED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="APPROVED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="PENDING" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option4" runat="server" Value="TRANSFERRED" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SuggestionStatusDataSource" runat="server"
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to send an email notification about the safety suggestion to the owner?')" 
                                OnClick="btnSendStatus_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void lnkSuggestionStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkSuggestionStatus = sender as LinkButton;

        //var safetySuggestionsId = 

        //get reference to the row selected 
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)lnkSuggestionStatus.NamingContainer;

        //set the selected index to the selected row so that the selected row will be highlighted
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = gvrow.RowIndex;

        //This HiddenField used to store the value of the ID
        HiddenField1.Value = gvrow.RowIndex.ToString();

        //show the modalPopUp
        modalPopUpExtender1.Show();
    }

    public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog SET StatusID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //reset the value of hiddenfield
            HiddenField1.Value = "-1";
        }

        GridView1.DataBind();

        //SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }
```

**I did not get any error, but the selected status in the ModalPopUp window is not reflected back to the GridView. Why?**

Answer (score 0):

in your btnSendStatus_Click, you update your database but not your gridview. It would seem you need to put

```
    gridview.databind()
```

at the end of that function.

Maybe adding a trigger to your update panel would help

```
    </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OKButton" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm assuming that its being updated in the database correctly. in your question I'm not sure if your saying your database isn't updating the information or your asp.net page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added it to my code, but nothing changed. Could you please look at my updated code above?